# python pandas read_csv thousands separator does not work

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I use pandas read_csv to read a simple csv file. However, it has `ValueError: could not convert string to float:` which I do not understand why.

The code is simply

```
rawdata = pd.read_csv( r'Journal_input.csv' ,
                      dtype = { 'Base Amount' : 'float64' } , 
                      thousands = ',' ,
                      decimal = '.',
                      encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
```

But I get this error

> pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read
>   (pandas\parser.c:10415)()
>
> pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory
>   (pandas\parser.c:10691)()
>
> pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows
>   (pandas\parser.c:11728)()
>
> pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_column_data
>   (pandas\parser.c:13162)()
>
> pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_tokens
>   (pandas\parser.c:14487)()
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '79,026,695.50'

How can it possible to get error when converting a string of '79,026,695.50' to float? I have already specified the two options

```
thousands = ',' ,
decimal = '.',
```

Is it some problem our my code or a bug in pandas?

Comment: Can you add content of file to question? Or better upload file to gdocs, dropbox.. if data not confidental?

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the row in question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is problem with `quoting`, because if separator is `,` and `thousands` is `,` too, some quoting has to be in `csv`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
import csv

temp=u"""'a','Base Amount'
'11','79,026,695.50'"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), 
                 dtype = { 'Base Amount' : 'float64' },
                 thousands = ',' ,
                 quotechar = "'",
                 quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL,
                 decimal = '.',
                 encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')

print (df)
    a  Base Amount
0  11   79026695.5

temp=u'''"a","Base Amount"
"11","79,026,695.50"'''
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), 
                 dtype = { 'Base Amount' : 'float64' },
                 thousands = ',' ,
                 quotechar = '"',
                 quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL,
                 decimal = '.',
                 encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')

print (df)
    a  Base Amount
0  11   79026695.5
```

Comment: this does not seem to work with int64

Answer (score 0):

First of all you get rid of the comma:
Example:

```
num = '79,026,695.50' 
print(num)
# '79,026,695.50'
num = num.replace(',', '') 
print(num)
79026695.50 
num = float(num)
```

in case:

```
rawdata['base_amount'] = rawdata['base_amount'].str.replace(',', '').astype(np.float64)
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem reading the CSV file in the first place.  Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to look over [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). An explanation of how and why your code works and addresses the question would be ideal.